# How to query within the same table

Tags: sql, join, self-join

I need to query a single table based on the contents of the same table

currently i have used `in` within `and`, which is taking a lot of time to query & i know its not the smartest way

```
PID CID Status
1   1   1
1   2   0
1   3   1
1   4   1
1   5   1
2   1   1
2   2   1
2   3   1
2   4   0
2   5   0
```

from the above table i need results which satisfy the following combination

```
Select PID from Tablename where 
(CID in (1) AND status 1)
AND
(CID in (2,3) AND status = 1)
AND
(CID in (4) AND status = 1)
AND 
(CID in (5) AND status = 1)
```

So as per above requirement, i should get only PID 1

Comment: You're using both `&` and `and` as boolean operators in your description. Is there any difference to those two? In SQL `and` and `or` are the two main where-operators. In some languages  (not SQL) `&`  means the same as `and` and `|` means `or`.

Comment: the query is just the sample, which i would need to look like. you can read & as AND. Wondering how i can achieve that combination based on the same table contents

Comment: If we should read `&` as `AND`, then why didn't you just write `AND` which is a valid SQL operator? What you then have is: `where cid in (1) and status=1 and cid in (2,3) and status=1 and cid in (4) and status=1 and cid in (5) and status=1` where `and status=1` are repeated unnecessarily and the `or` inside `in` should be just a comma.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Please add expected result as a table.

Answer (score 1):

This should get all the PIDs which exist in all the select statements:

```
SELECT PID FROM TableName WHERE CID = 1 AND Status = 1
INTERSECT
SELECT PID FROM TableName WHERE CID IN (2, 3) AND Status = 1
INTERSECT
SELECT PID FROM TableName WHERE CID = 4 AND Status = 1
INTERSECT
SELECT PID FROM TableName WHERE CID = 5 AND Status = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want:

```
Select PID
from Tablename 
where status = 1
group by PID
having sum(case when CID in (1) then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when CID in (2, 3) then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when CID in (4) then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when CID in (5) then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

Your query only tests values within a single row.  The `where` condition can never evaluate to true.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=51632a140458f1187ca8cd05fc6c23aa) is a db<>fiddle, showing that this returns PID = 1 for the data in your example.

Comment: Hey gordon thanks for quick reply, but i need PID which satisfy this CID combination having status as 1 for (1 & (2 or 3) & 4 & 5) as per the above data PID 1 satisfies this criteria

Comment: @SachinMK . . . I added a db<>fiddle to show you that this works.